i have a issue with inserting image filed in django database
This is my model:
from django.db import models


class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Article(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=6000)

    featured_image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True, default="default.jpg") 
                                                            # i want to add this filed
    content = models.TextField() 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

I have installed python -m pip install pillow and this is my setting configuration:
import os  

STATIC_URL = '/static/'  

STATICFILES_DIRS = [     
    BASE_DIR / 'static'  
]

In the admin panel, I'm expecting the apparition of the featured image field that sets the image with the  default.jpg
If I try creating an article in the admin it doesn't insert the image.
After I run python manage.py makemigrations it is always gives me this:

It is impossible to change a nullable field 'topic' on the article to non-nullable without providing a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:

Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)

Ignore for now. Existing rows that contain NULL values will have to be handled manually, for example with a RunPython or RunSQL operation.

Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.


Select an option:

No matter what I pick I still don't see the file in the Django admin

It is not in static, but in media.

Can you also explain what you changed between the previous migration?

So the STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT are different to the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT which you need to use for uploads. With this in mind here is a crude example to get you going.
settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media' # directory where media files will be stored.

urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

# you might want to add STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT here also so static assets are served.

By adding the static() to the urlpatterns you are allowing django to serve the media assets.

Please note that this is a solution for local dev, in production, you would offload this to nginx or some other server.

If you are wanting a "default image", you can now add a default jpeg to the media folder and that will be used for instances where you do not upload a file.

i have these in settings.py:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/' # added by me
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / 'static'
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/images')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')

ad also these in urls.py in root foder:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

a thing that worked was adding default=1 in topic filed in Article class.
